# updating a component using NuGet, when one project in the solution is already updated to the latest one

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a  general framework project which is referenced by many solutions.  Whenever there is an update to a component which I would like to upgrade to, I normally right-click on the solution > Manage NuGet packages for solution > upgrade component for all projects.  The problem is that for all other solutions, their projects (except from the common referenced one) is not updated to the latest one.  If I try to do the same, it will not let me click on 'Update' to update all projects, as it detects that one project is already using the latest version. I have some other 4 or 5 projects in most solutions, and it is quite a headache to update them manually.  Any ideas about it?  I am using the latest version of NuGet and VS2012.

Comment: We have (in alpha at least), a Visual Studio extension that helps alleviate this problem: http://inedo.com/company/news/announcing-proget-20-and-proget-client-tools

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the outdated project in the solution and select Manage NuGet Packages from the context menu.  Your Manage NuGet Packages window will now only affect the scope of that one project you selected and you should be able to perform an update to the project directly.  Repeat for all your other packages.